# How to set the volume for a specific app?

Tags: java, android

How can I set the volume only for my App. I want code an alarm. It should ring even if the system sound is silently, but I doesn't want set the sound for all apps loudly.

Comment: you can't do that. For the sound, you have to use 1 of the system sound channels (ring, notifications, music, alarm,...). And if it is muted - you either have to change the channel volume, or do nothing and your sound will be muted.

Comment: Okay thank you. If you post this in an answer, then I can mark the question as solved

Comment: I'm not 100% sure in that, therefore let it be a comment better. Probably there is some hack which I don't know about